# Adding javascript to moodle assignment page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, moodle

I am working on a page in moodle that allows you to edit submissions. There is a tinymce editor that saves changes to a submission using a save button.
I am looking to automate the saving using javascript. I have my js code, but i am not sure of how to include the javascript on the page.

Url is like this: `www.somewebsite.com/mod/assign/view.php?id=1234&action=editsubmission`

I am new to moodle and php so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In Moodle 2.0 this is used `$PAGE->requires->js()`.

Make `$PAGE` available to your code by doing:

```
require_once($CFG->libdir . '/pagelib.php');
global $PAGE;
```

Add your code:

```
$PAGE->requires->js( new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/mod/mymod/script.js') );
```

It is required to put `moodle_url()` around your path!

Comment: use $PAGE->requires->js( new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/mod/mymod/script.js') , true); to load js at the bottom of page

Answer (score 2):

You can add JavaScript to the Additional HTML in Moodle
[image]

As it is HTML, you will need to enclose your JavaScript in `<script>` tags. You can use jQuery or JavaScript. Be sure to target the specific elements you want, and not to affect other pages, as this will add the script to every page in your Moodle instance.

The benefit of this approach is that you don't need to update the `view.php` file every time you upgrade Moodle.

Comment: additional note: if you use jQuery in any other area than Turnitin, where it is enabled, you will have to include the jQuery library file

Answer (score 0):

placed this in the view.php file:

```
$PAGE->requires->js( new moodle_url($CFG->dirroot . '/mod/assign/myscript.js'));
```